# Set description meta tag

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have recently added the following line of Javascript code to a few pages on my site, in order to pull the title tag from the H1 element with the CSS class of "Category-H1".

```
document.title = document.getElementsByClassName("Category-H1")[0].innerHTML;
```

I am curious, can I do something similar to pull in the description tag using JS from my H2 element?

Comment: Learn the basics of the DOM: `document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Your question title says "set", but you seem to be asking how to "get" - can you clarify what you're wanting to do? Please show the relevant html.

Comment: He wants to set the content of the description meta tag, I believe the question is valid.

Comment: right, I understand that portion of how to set it to a different element. What I dont understand is the document.title part - as far as I could find out, there is no document.description

Comment: For clarification - hopefully I word this correctly. I want to "pull" the text from the h2 element on my page, and set this text to be in the meta description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is doable, but I'm not sure if it would accomplish what you're hoping for. Most people use meta description tags for SEO purposes, but many (most?) search engines won't recognize the description if it is set by JavaScript after the page loads*. Still, if you want to do this:

```
var meta=document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
for (var i=0; i<meta.length; i++) {
    if (meta[i].name.toLowerCase()=="description") {
        meta[i].content=document.getElementsByClassName("Category-H1")[0].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

*Frankly, I don't speak from *experience* here, just common sense. It really doesn't make sense for meta information to be dynamic, so even if a spider was smart enough to run JavaScript, why would it recheck meta information after doing so?

Comment: You are right. I know it's not the proper way to add a title tag, but unfortunately for me, the pages are generated dynamically using asp.net, and while the module generating the pages does support adding html content, and url keywords, it does not support adding meta tags.

Comment: After doing some research, I found this blog post http://www.ifinity.com.au/2012/10/04/Changing_a_Page_Title_with_Javascript_to_update_a_Google_SERP_Entry Anything in the title tag is better than nothing, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getAttribute()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) function to do this:

```
document.title = document.getElementsByClassName("Category-H1")[0].getAttribute("yourDescriptionMetaTag");
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is going to be good for SEO.  While it may work, I don't think spiders are expecting these tags to be dynamic.  But if SEO isn't the point, here's another answer that shows how with jquery.

[Javascript To Change Metadata / Metatags Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231845/javascript-to-change-metadata-metatags-dynamically)