# Quick help scaling a website

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, zooming, scale

I try to set the initial scale of this [website](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/).

I tried this:

```
document.body.style.zoom = '0.8';
```

and this:

```
document.body.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
```

Unfortunatelly the slider of the timeperiod-bar looses it´s functionality. Does anyone know a workaraound for that? Thanks everyone for ideas.

UPDATE: New approach:

```
var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
metaTag.name = "viewport"
metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8, maximum-scale=0.8, user-scalable=0"
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
```

Here, nothing happens at all.

EDIT: Another approach:

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute(
          'content', 
          'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8, user-scalable=no');
```

unfortunately no success.

Comment: answer has been re-updated. try it out.

Answer (score 1):

To set the initial scale, you need to adjust your viewport in the meta.

Currently , your meta tag sets the scale to 1

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Change the 1.0 to 0.8 and it should adjust accordingly.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8" />
```

For what it's worth, I resized it using my browser window, and the zoom still worked fine when I clicked on the buttons. 
(The bar doesn't seem to work even at full screen; I have a 15" laptop and the bar slider didn't work, but the buttons work; you can maybe hide the bar?)

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

The allowable values for `user-scalable` are **yes** or **no**, not 0 and 1. 
Set user-scalable to no if you want it to be non-scalable. Also set the `initial-scale` as well as the `maximum-scale`

**RE-EDIT**

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9232064/1675954  for how to edit meta tags using jquery

The javascript solution: follow this syntax

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute("content", _desc);
```

See [this article](https://webdevdoor.com/responsive-web-design/change-viewport-meta-tag-javascript) also for updating for media queries

Comment: @ Rachel: thank you for your help. I think I´m limited to javascript, cause I have to set the scale in a WKUserscript in Swift. Didn´t really understand what you mean with fullscreen? Setting the page in my browser (Safari, Chrome)  to fullscreen, the slidebar works fine.

Comment: @ Rachel: I tried to execute your suggestion in javascript. See update.

Comment: @JoschHazard answer edited. Also see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: @ Rachel: Mine is 15" as well. I´m trying the script from above in Chrome DevTools. Even with `user-scalable` yes or no, nothing happens.

Comment: @JoschHazard yes i tried it again just now and it worked fine at full screen. momentary glitch i think! (meta is still at 1.0) try putting a test page live with the new meta tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149035/discussion-between-josch-hazard-and-rachel-gallen).

Comment: @ Rachel: just trying `var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");` returns `undefined` in Chrome DevTools.

Comment: @ Rachel: It seems like `("meta[name=viewport]")` doesn´t exist in this document. But I can see it in the head.

Comment: this would indicate that your viewport has not been set already in the head section. however it appears on your live page. so how did you set it previously? this syntax is for updating the meta

Comment: the article suggests using document.getElementById("viewport")

Comment: @ Rachel: But this was what you suggested me: updating the meta. I posted my last approach above.

Comment: yes, but i know of multiple ways to update and set the viewport. try getElementById

Comment: @ Rachel: I appreciate your effort! But still, all i need is a working javascript to set the initial scale of this specific site to 0.8.

Comment: @ Rachel: I upvoted your answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Window Resizer has been a life saver checking if webpages works across all platforms.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en

Comment: @ D88naimi: In what way could this solve my problem?