# html : Choose a <meta> title name from an url variable

Tags: html, var

I have a webpage start like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>France : carte paysagère</title> 
<meta name="description" content="Nouvelle carte avec indications utiles pour le voyage et le tourisme." />
```

I have lots of pages, so is there a way to automatize things like a

http://mappingforyou.eu/france would have a title of "France : carte paysagère"
http://mappingforyou.eu/ukir would have a title of "UK/Ireland: landscape map"

and so on. same for the description.

thanks..

Comment: with vanilla javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553569/17716837

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a lot of pages?  Or do you already have a lot of existing pages and want to change them?

**1) Create pages (from data) with a static site builder**

A static site builder is a program you run locally on your computer.
You can read the data from a database or JSON files, or some API.
You write some templates and some logic, then run the site builder,
and many HTML documents are created.

These HTMl documents you can then upload to webspace somewhere.

If you already have a favorite programming language, you can find
a static site builder in your favorite language. Here's a
[list of different static site builders](https://jamstack.org/generators/)

**2) Create pages (from data) with a backend programming language**

With a backend programming language the html pages are created "on the fly",
when a browser tries to access them. You can read the data from a database or JSON files or APIs.  You write some templates and some logic, then upload
the programm to a webspace that supports your language.

If you already have a favorite language you can probably
use it: PHP, JavaScript, Ruby, Python, ... they can all be used
in this way.  And you can find tutorials and online courses for all
of them.

**3) Create pages from existing HTML pages with a web scaper**

If you are dealing with a lot of pre-existing HTML-Pages that you
want to change (translate?) you can use a tool for webscraping.
The tool will help you to analyse the existing pages,
do some changes on them, and then write out new pages.

I can recommend `mechanize` in Ruby, but I'm sure there are equivalent
libraries in other languages.